# XPath cannot detect class name when contains return char

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I have a problem with XPath selector. When the class name has return char(or may be for another reason!) it cannot  select the node by class name. Anyone can help me?

```
var html = 
    @"<INPUT class=box value=John maxLength=16 size=16 name=user_name>
      <INPUT class='  
        box1' value=Tony maxLength=16 size=16 name=user_name>
        ";

    var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

    var htmlNodes = 
        htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input[@class='box1']");
    Console.WriteLine(htmlNodes == null);

    htmlNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input[@class='box']");
    Console.WriteLine(htmlNodes == null);
```

In the first input tag classname is in the same line with class but in the second input element class name is the below line.

The result of first console is **True** and for the second is **False**

https://dotnetfiddle.net/HGP9H3

Comment: can you try with `//input[contains(@class,'box1')]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `@class` value of `box1` contains a line break and some spaces. So the check of the predicate in the expression

```
//input[@class='box1']
```

fails and you get a `true` for the null check.

You have two possibilities to fix that:

1. Remove all spaces/line breaks with `normalize-space` in the predicate like this:

   ```
   //input[normalize-space(@class)='box1']
   ```
2. Remove the line break from the HTML snippet like this:

   ```
   var html = 
     @"<INPUT class=box value=John maxLength=16 size=16 name=user_name>
       <INPUT class='box1' value=Tony maxLength=16 size=16 name=user_name>
   ";
   ```

Comment: I cannot do the second suggestion. Because I don't create it. But the first one works to me.